# Unable to import SVG with Vite as ReactComponent

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

Tried to use this library: [vite-plugin-react-svg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-react-svg)

and had no success by importing it like:

```
import { ExternalLink } from 'assets/svg/link-external.svg?component';
```

Are there any workarounds for this issue?

The error i got before was the following:

```
import { ReactComponent as ExternalLink } from 'assets/svg/link-external.svg';

//Uncaught SyntaxError: 
  The requested module '/src/assets/svg/link-external.svg?import'
  does not provide an export named 'ReactComponent'
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Anyone having issues with the accepted answer, try the solution described in this package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-svgr

`import { ReactComponent as Logo } from './logo.svg'`

For some reason, I couldn't build using the accepted answer

Comment: Thanks. Best answer for working with SVGs in the same way as CRA. Worked like a charm with styled-components.

Comment: Why this is not the accepted answer is unexplainable. Please refer to my comment in the... _accepted_ answer for why that's wrong and yours points into the right direction.

Comment: In my case the use of ReactComponent did not work. However when using the notation from the docs it worked without problems: https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html
Might have been changed recently?

Comment: Thanks. I just follow the guide. `vite-plugin-svgr@^3.2.0` works for me but @4.xx doesn't work.

Answer (score 104):

#### Update October 2023 - `vite-plugin-svgr` version ^4.0.0

When importing your SVG file using `vite-plugin-svgr` (see below), make sure to use [the newly added `?react` query suffix](https://github.com/pd4d10/vite-plugin-svgr/releases/tag/v4.0.0) on your imported file, which allows you to use the default export and skip the `ReactComponent` aliasing:

```js
import ReactLogo from './assets/react.svg?react'

<ReactLogo />
```

If you're using TypeScript, you'll also need to add the following at the *very top* of your file (before the `import` statements):

```js
/// <reference types="vite-plugin-svgr/client" />
```

#### Update 2023

Use `vite-plugin-svgr`

1. Add `SVGR` to the project

`yarn add vite-plugin-svgr`

2. Register the plugin `SVGR` to vite in `vite.config.js`

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import svgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr' 

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(), 
    svgr({ 
      svgrOptions: {
        // svgr options
      },
    }),
  ], 
})
```

3. In `App.tsx` import SVG as React Component :

```js
import { ReactComponent as ReactLogo } from './assets/react.svg'

<ReactLogo />
```

---

Stackblitz Examples:

- [standard project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-qxmcr1)
- [using Dynamic SVG project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-dofkxp)

References:

- Learn more about **[SVGR](https://github.com/gregberge/svgr)** at https://react-svgr.com/docs/ecosystem/#articles
- [plugin options](https://github.com/pd4d10/vite-plugin-svgr#options)
- list of [SVGR options](https://react-svgr.com/docs/options/) that can be added to `svgrOptions:{}`:

Bonus:

- [Dynamic SVG component](https://dev.to/mondal10/dynamic-svg-component-in-vite-react-ts-3pih) by *Amit Mondal*

---

Note:
*Previous plugin @honkhonk/vite-plugin-svgr is deprecated (thanks Richard Fernandez for pointing it)*

Comment: While the proposed specific plugin version didn't work me, this one did: `yarn add -D vite-plugin-svgr`, combined with this syntax: `import { ReactComponent as Happy } from './assets/svg/happy.svg'`. This practically emulates how react-scripts does it, and might be useful for anyone migrating from react-scripts to vite.

Comment: @miek no luck with either, and my approach in the answer below

Comment: Careful of this above answer... the `@honkhonk` seems to be an archived fork. Best to take from the official source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-svgr

Comment: I'm going to insist that people actually **run their code** before psoting here. The syntax `svgr({ svgrOptions({ // svgr options }), })`, (here in one line) is worng! Not only `svgrOptions` is not a function, but also you can't just open `{}`s and dump stuff inside like it's a Python set, or something. What you wanted to say was `svgr({ svgrOptions: { // svgr options }, })`.

Comment: I actually could not use this as the IDE complained about the `?react` part (and it seems ugly), so I just added the path to the include options: `svgr({ include: '**/*.svg' })`

Comment: can also add 
```
/// <reference types="vite-plugin-svgr/client" />
```
to `vite-env.d.ts` file to get rid of the ts cannot find module error when using new `?react`

Comment: If you don't use ?react at the end and do a custom pattern like I did, then the type does not works. I had to change it back.

Answer (score 21):

You should use [`@svgr/rollup`](https://github.com/gregberge/svgr/tree/main/packages/rollup) instead of `vite-plugin-svgr`.
`vite-plugin-svgr` is not a good choice, because it doesn't support `svgo`, and it use `esbuild` to transform some svg code, it may have some problem in es5 environment.

The worst thing is `vite-plugin-svgr` can't add `svgo` plugin, see this issue: https://github.com/pd4d10/vite-plugin-svgr/issues/49.

```bash
npm install @svgr/rollup -D
```

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import svgr from '@svgr/rollup';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), svgr()]
});
```

Answer (score 11):

`yarn add -D vite-plugin-svgr` will be the best choice as it keeps being maintained.

```
// vite.config.js
import svgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr'

export default {
  plugins: [svgr()],
}
```

```js
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from './logo.svg'
```

Also you can import as default by setting up this config option in `vite.config.js`.

```js
svgr({
  exportAsDefault: true
})
```

```js
// now you can import as default
import Logo from './logo.svg'
```

But notice that it will overrides the default behavior of Vite which exports the URL as default.

---

If you have any typescript issues, there is also a declaration helper for better type inference

```js
/// <reference types="vite-plugin-svgr/client" />
```

Comment: best answer =) thanks

Comment: Woo, learning about `exportAsDefault` saved me after an hour of searching. Note that `exportAsDefault` only exists in `vite-plugin-svgr` version `3.x.x` or lower. I couldn't find any equivalent option for version `4.x.x`

Comment: It seems in 4.x you can just export the SVG directly without casting to a `ReactComponent`

Answer (score 3):

I migrated from CRA to Vite and was facing this problem, I followed the above steps but did not work for me. I went to the official documentation of Vite and found that I needed to add

```
 "types": ["vite/client"],
```

inside my tsConfig.json file which will then enable the support for svgs and couple of other things.

More information - https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#typescript

Comment: Adding `types` to the config is slightly different in v4 of vite. Check the docs [here](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#client-types).

Answer (score 3):

Use `@svgx/vite-plugin-react`

install it

```
npm i @svgx/vite-plugin-react
```

and include it in your vite.config.js file

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import svgx from "@svgx/vite-plugin-react";

export default defineConfig(async () => {
  return {
    plugins: [
      svgx()
    ],
  };
});
```

and then import your svg as react component

```js
import MyIcon from "./icon.svg?component";
```

You can import the svg as "component" or "url" or "raw"

See its [documentation on github](https://github.com/salihbenlalla/svgx/tree/main/packages/vite-plugin-react)

The best part about this plugin is that you can import the svg files dynamically. ie: if you want to import an svg using a variable name you can do that like this:

```js
import importVars from "@svgx-dir:/path/to/directory";

export default function (props) {
  const MyIcon = importVars(props.iconName);
  return (
    <div>
      <MyIcon color="#FF5733" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now you can pass a variable to importVars function to import an svg dynamically.

Comment: Thanks, Every other solution I tried wasn't working in an Astro project. The dynamic import is neat!

Answer (score 3):

For an Ionic React application, I had to:

1. Install `vite-plugin-svgr` and register it in `vite.config.js` as per the accepted answer.
2. Add a `custom.d.ts` file to the project with the following content:

   ```
   declare module '*.svg?react' {
       import React = require('react');
       export const ReactComponent: React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;
       const src: string;
       export default src;
   }
   ```

   And add it in `include` in `tsconfig.json`:

   ```
   "include": ["src", "custom.d.ts"],`
   ```
3. Use the SVG like so:

   ```
   import MyIcon from "/src/components/icons/MyIcon.svg?react";

   <MyIcon/>
   ```

Comment: Thanks, it helped to fix TS error 'Cannot find module...' while importing via {path}.svg?react

Comment: But TS started to throw errors that I'm adding className to <SomeSvg /> because type is string. To fix this I removed the line: const src: string. And changed last line to export default ReactComponent

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue but wanted to avoid using external packages.

following [@user8659363](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74515521/3238390)'s answer -

My solution was to create a new file under `src` directory, and reference it to vite's types -

src/**vite-env.d.ts**

content:

```js
/// <reference types="vite/client" />
```

Here you can see  the full list of supported modules/extensions - https://github.com/vitejs/vite/blob/32c5a9a618b625c707703ede05215e499ee1744b/packages/vite/client.d.ts#L129

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i also been able to import SVG's in vite without using external packages, maybe they patched it.

Answer (score 1):

if you create the app using vite, then you need to install this package  [vite-plugin-svgr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-svgr)

and import the asset like

```
import Logo from './logo.svg?react'
```

add `?react` at the end of the asset path

Also, remember to update the vite config file like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-svgr#usage)

```
// vite.config.js

import svgr from "vite-plugin-svgr";

export default {

  // ...

  plugins: [svgr()],

};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to import svg files as ReactComponent without ?react suffix then override vite.config.ts file as follows:

```
export default defineConfig({
  // ...
  plugins: [
    // ...
    svgr({
      svgrOptions: { exportType: 'named', ref: true, svgo: false, titleProp: true },
      include: '**/*.svg',
    }),
    // ...
  ],
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid svgr by importing like this an assigning to an img

```
import logo from "./logo-login.svg"
<img src={logo} className="w-24 inline-block" alt="logo" />
```

Comment: but then it's no React component so not at all helpful to answer OPs question

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue after installing this package:

`npm i vite-plugin-svgr`

```
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import svgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr'; // make sure to import it

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react(), svgr()],
});

// App.jsx
import {ReactComponent as ExternalLink} from './assets/svg/link-external.svg';

<ExternalLink />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me...

**package.json**

```
{
    ...
    "devDependencies": {
        ...
        "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.0",
        "vite-plugin-svgr": "^4.2.0"
    }
}
```

**vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import svgr from "vite-plugin-svgr";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig(
    {
        ...
        plugins: [
            react(), 
            svgr()
        ]
    }
)
```

**src/declaration.d.ts**

```
/// <reference types="vite-plugin-svgr/client" />
```

The above makes `*.svg?react` modules visible to `tsc` (TypeScript compiler), avoiding the syntax error on the `import`. This only matters when invoking `tsc` (e.g. to perform type-check), not when bundling by Vite (which works independently from `tsc`).

You can achieve a similar effect by adding "vite-plugin-svgr/client" to [types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types) (in **tsconfig.json**), but that then turns-off the visibility of other `@types` packages, so you must either add them back manually or fiddle with [typeRoots](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots).

You could also put the above `<reference>` directly in the `.tsx` files which import SVGs, but that would be less practical if you have many such files.

**src/MyComponent.tsx**

```
import MyImage from "../some/path/MyImage.svg?react";
```

Note the `?react` at the end.

You should now be able to put `<MyImage />` inside your JSX code.

Answer (score 0):

I might be late to the party. However, let me share just in case :D

I had problems finding all loading options under 1 plugin. So I came up with a Vite Plugin that merges all loading strategies in one. Here's `vite-plugin-react-rich-svg`, it can load svg files as those;

- Components with SVGR (*.svg?component)
- Data URL (`"data:image/svg+xml;..."`), ideal for inline importing on demand: (*.svg?url)
- Raw HTML string, ideal when you need the file as it is (*.svg?raw)
- Base64 encoded string, ideal if you need the file for networking purposes (*.svg?base64)

Github Repo: https://github.com/iGoodie/vite-plugin-react-rich-svg

NPM Page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-react-rich-svg

Happy Coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

1. install pkg `npm i vite-plugin-svgr`
2. import with react `import AnyName from '../../assets/svgs/icon.svg?react';`
3. use in jsx `<AnyName />`

Answer (score -3):

I had the same issue as well, the [npm vite-plugin-svgr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-svgr) documentation explains it very well in how to add it and use it with vite.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).