# Typescript errors when using a suffix (?raw, ?url etc

Tags: typescript, vite

I get a typescript error in my vite project when I try to import an SVG with a suffix (?component). How can I configure typescript to ignore these suffixes?

`TS2307: Cannot find module './desktop-mark.svg?component' or its corresponding type declarations.`

```
import DesktopLogoMark from './desktop-mark.svg?component';
```

Comment: Why do you need the suffix?

Comment: This was the only way I could get the SVG imports to work. Here is the post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70309561/unable-to-import-svg-with-vite-as-reactcomponent

Comment: See: https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#client-types

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add module declaration: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#wildcard-module-declarations

E.g. in `declarations.d.ts`:

```
declare module "*?raw"
{
    const content: string;
    export default content;
}
```

Comment:  thanks, this works: 
```
declare module "*?component" {
  const content: string;
  export default content;
}
```