# unable to transform svg from database to react component

Tags: reactjs, svg, jsx, vite

I want to display an svg image imported from a database as a React component :

```
<SvgImageToDisplay
  viewBox={viewBox}
  onWheel={onMouseWheel}
  onMouseDown={onMouseDown}
  onMouseMove={onMouseMove}
  onMouseUp={onMouseUp}
  onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}
/>
```

It's well possible to display an svg image imported locally using "vite-plugin-svgr" as indicated on the post [importSvgWithViteAsReactComponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70309561/unable-to-import-svg-with-vite-as-reactcomponent) :

`import { ReactComponent as SvgImageToDisplay} from '../../svgImages/svgImageTest.svg';`

In the case the svg image is imported from a database with a string format (decoded with atob function for example), how can the svg image be transformed as a React component ?

---

A possibility is maybe to use the "transform" function from svgr, as indicated for example in [reactSvgrNode](https://react-svgr.com/docs/node-api/) :

```
import { transform } from '@svgr/core'

const SvgImageToDisplay = await transform(
  svgImageToDisplayDecodedFromBackend
)
```

But this generates error

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: process is not defined

maybe linked to the use of vite-plugin-svgr ? (solution above recommended for Node.js)

Comment: finally found a compatible alternative to svgr with react-inlinesvg - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-inlinesvg :

import SVG from 'react-inlinesvg';
<Svg
  src={svgImageToDisplayDecodedFromBackend}
  viewBox={viewBox}
  onWheel={onMouseWheel}
  onMouseDown={onMouseDown}
  onMouseMove={onMouseMove}
  onMouseUp={onMouseUp}
  onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}
/>