# How to use Styled Components with SVG in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, vite, styled-components

**bundler: vite**

**svg**

```
<svg width="current" height="currnet" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M13.8941 3.0726C13.5536 2.73193 13.1493 2.46169 12.7043 2.27732C12.2593 2.09295 11.7824 1.99805 11.3007 1.99805C10.8191 1.99805 10.3421 2.09295 9.89716 2.27732C9.45219 2.46169 9.0479 2.73193 8.7074 3.0726L8.00073 3.77926L7.29406 3.0726C6.60627 2.3848 5.67342 1.9984 4.70073 1.9984C3.72804 1.9984 2.79519 2.3848 2.1074 3.0726C1.4196 3.76039 1.0332 4.69324 1.0332 5.66593C1.0332 6.63862 1.4196 7.57147 2.1074 8.25926L2.81406 8.96593L8.00073 14.1526L13.1874 8.96593L13.8941 8.25926C14.2347 7.91876 14.505 7.51447 14.6893 7.0695C14.8737 6.62453 14.9686 6.14759 14.9686 5.66593C14.9686 5.18427 14.8737 4.70733 14.6893 4.26236C14.505 3.81739 14.2347 3.4131 13.8941 3.0726Z" fill="current" stroke="current" stroke-width="1.36774" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
</svg>
```

**LikeButton component**

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { ReactComponent as Icon } from "@/assets/icons/heart.svg";

const HeartIcon = styled(Icon)`
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  fill: red;
`;
export default function LikeButton() {
  return <HeartIcon />;
}
```

**Test Component**

```
import LikeButton from "@/components/LikeButton/LikeButton";

export default function Test() {
  return <LikeButton />;
}
```

**error message**

`Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/src/assets/icons/heart.svg?import' does not provide an export named 'ReactComponent' (at LikeButton.jsx:2:10)`

**question**

How do I create an SVG with a styled component? A reference would be appreciated!

I used the vite bundler and also installed the svgr plugin, but I get an error like above.

Comment: are you using next.js?

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what exactly the problem is, need to see more of the folder structure but with Vite bundler, it is best to put your assets like .svg or .png into the **public** folder instead of **src/assets**

Comment: If so, should I put all the SVG files I use inside the component in the pulic folder?

Comment: @ctr_nike Yes that is correct, after putting your assets into the public folder, just use the file name directly to use it. Like so:
<img src="mysvg.svg" />

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your import syntax (i.e. `import { ReactComponent as Icon } from "@/assets/icons/heart.svg";`), it seems as though you're following examples from `create-react-app` which uses [SVGR](https://react-svgr.com/) under the hood to import SVGs. To achieve the same with vite, you can use the [`vite-plugin-svgr`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-svgr), for example, like so:

```
npm install --save-dev vite-plugin-svgr
```

Then in your `vite.config.ts`:

```
import svgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr';

export default defineConfig({
  // ...
  plugins: [
    svgr(),
    // ...
  ]
  // ...
})
```

Following that, you can import SVGs like so:

```
import HeartIcon from '@/assets/icons/heart.svg';
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70309561/unable-to-import-svg-with-vite-as-reactcomponent

I solved it with method 1 in this link.