# Error in ReactComponent when importing .svg image into a React project with Vite

Tags: reactjs, react-tsx

I have this code to import a .svg image, but it is not working, 'ReactComponent' is underlined in red indicating an error and the image does not render on the screen.

```
    import { ReactComponent as GithubIcon } from './assets/img/github.svg';

function App() {
  return (
    <header>
      <nav>
        <div>
          <h1>DSMovie</h1>
          <a href="https://github.com/devsuperior">
            <div>
              <GithubIcon />
              <p>/devsuperior</p>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
  )
}

export default App;
```

I haven't found a solution yet, I'm waiting for help!

Answer (score 0):

Check this.

[Unable to import SVG with Vite as ReactComponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70309561/unable-to-import-svg-with-vite-as-reactcomponent?rq=1)